# For a base 1st-level spell, can a Scribes wizard use the Master Scrivener feature to copy it at 2nd level (before its power is enhanced)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, spellcasting

[Master Scrivener](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#MasterScrivener-2986122), the 10th-level feature of [Order of Scribes wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes), is described as follows (TCoE, p. 78):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can create one magic scroll by
> touching your Wizardly Quill to a blank piece of paper or parchment
> and causing one spell from your Awakened Spellbook to be copied onto
> the scroll.
>
> The spellbook must be within 5 feet of you when you make the scroll.
> The chosen spell must be of 1st or 2nd level and must have a casting
> time of 1 action. Once in the scroll, the spell’s power is enhanced,
> counting as one level higher than normal. You can cast the spell from
> the scroll by reading it as an action. The scroll is unintelligible to
> anyone else, and the spell vanishes from the scroll when you cast it
> or when you finish your next long rest.

Obviously, the best would be to make it a 2nd-level scroll, thus getting a 2nd-level spell upcast to 3rd level.

But say you wanted a benefit that only a 1st-level spell had (say, *Magic Missile*'s automatic damage). Could you copy a 2nd-level version of that spell into the scroll, and then the scroll would let you cast it at 3rd level? Or could you only copy the 1st-level version of the spell, for a final result of 2nd-level *Magic Missile*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### In this case, *Magic Missile* would be a second level spell.

The Scriveners ability allows you to *copy* a spell out of your spell book onto a scroll, and it is treated as one level higher than *normal*. The normal spell level for *Magic Missile* is level 1, and is only boosted to level 2 when cast using a level 2 slot. Since you aren't casting it with a level 2 slot, only its base level of 1 is used, bumping it to level 2 spell on the scroll.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117529/discussion-on-answer-by-revenantbacon-can-you-upcast-spells-for-master-scrivener).